# Flutter/Firestore - Error: A value of type 'List<String> Function(QuerySnapshot)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a dynamic list view which displays document ids from Firebase. I have created the list of events from snapshot:

```
    List<String> _eventListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
    return doc.documentID == null ? doc.documentID : ' ';
  }).toList();
}
```

But when I come to build the stream using this code:

```
    Stream<List<String>> get events {
  return DatabaseService().eventsCollection.snapshots().map((event) => _eventListFromSnapshot);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: A value of type 'List<String> Function(QuerySnapshot)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot calling function `_eventListFromSnapshot`.
Fix like this

```dart
Stream<List<String>> get events {
  return DatabaseService()
    .eventsCollection
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => _eventListFromSnapshot(snapshot));
}
```

or simpler:

```dart
Stream<List<String>> get events {
  return DatabaseService()
    .eventsCollection
    .snapshots().map(_eventListFromSnapshot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to do it explicitly. 
Try something like this in your method.

```
List<String> _eventListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    List<String> docIDs = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < snapshot.documents.length; i++){
        String value = snapshot.documents[i].documentID ?? " "; 
        docIDs.add(value);
    }
    return docIDs;
}
```

or else, we might have an issue in this line,

```
Stream<List<String>> get events {
  return DatabaseService().eventsCollection.snapshots().map((event) => _eventListFromSnapshot(event));
}
```

We have to call the function, instead of assigning it maybe.

Hope this solves your issue.